# SendGrid webhook returns 404 to ngrok

Tags: sendgrid, ngrok, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using a webhook to listen for Mail Send events (open, click), and I keep getting 404 being returned to my ngrok URL. If I use a webhook tester URL, it works.
Is there a configuration issue that needs to be set with ngrok and SendGrid?

Comment: What ngrok command are you running and where's your local web server running to handle the requests?

Comment: command: ngrok http portnumber.                                                                                            
My local webserver is running on Nodejs.

Comment: ngrok has a dashboard that's running when you start your tunnel at localhost:4000. Check that to inspect the HTTP request in more detail.

Comment: It is possible that your nodejs app is responding with 404.

Comment: My nodejs app isn't responding with 404. I tried to call that endpoint from postman and it was hitting my local server. However, the ngrok tunnel returns 404 not found.

Comment: Can you post the entire request that you see in the ngrok dashboard? This may help us figure out what's going on on your machine.

Comment: ngrok isn’t showing me anything but the configuration information. Could you please tell me what information you are looking for?

Comment: My bad, I think I shared the wrong port number. When you run ngrok, there's a URL next to the "Web Interface" label, likely it'll be localhost:4040.
Go to that URL to find the dashboard that's locally running. You can inspect incoming HTTP requests and outgoing HTTP responses there. Find your 404 there and share it with us.

Comment: Thanks, can you show what's in the raw response? I'm curious to see the headers especially.

Comment: That's still the HTTP request, what about the HTTP response?
FYI, I recommend removing those images, or redacting the PII and other sensitive data.

Comment: Here is the  http response https://imgur.com/P9WEoxf

Comment: Interesting, either your node.js or some other server is handling your webhook request and returning a 404 error.
Unfortunately you can't tell from the response who is actually handling the request.

Comment: In some cases, multiple applications listen to the same port, for example, app 1 listens to your private IP + port, while your node.js app listens to you localhost + port. ngrok may route the HTTP request to the application listening to the private IP + port.

Comment: Try explicitly adding `localhost:port` in the ngrok command instead of just the port number. so `ngrok http http://localhost:port` to force ngrok to listen to the port on localhost.

Comment: Okay, how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried using `ngrok http http://localhost:port`

Comment: I did that, but the issue persists

Comment: Then it could be your node.js application is returning the 404. When you send cURL commands to your localhost:port/your_event_path, it works fine?

Comment: Thanks, @Swimburger. My bad, I figured it out, I was not adding my base URL to the ngrok link. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should answer your own question on here.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was calling the wrong route. This fixed it for me, I changed from /event to /api/v1/event.

I initially called the route like this /api/v1/event but, I did not get any trigger from SendGrid then I removed it. I realized that it takes time for SendGrid to make a post request to my route because of the queuing system.